# Why is it when I return a `double` from a `void *` function, it becomes incompatible?

Tags: c, types, double, void

I am making a generic programming library, used to make my life a little bit easier when programming in C. The problem I ran across was that when returning a `double` from a `void *` function, it results in an `incompatible types` error. Why is that? I thought void * was supposed to return any datatype, and not just select ones?

main.c

```
void * _example_code();

int main(void) {
    double res = _example_code();
}

void * _example_code() {
    return 2.23;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Not all types are automatically converted to `void *`, just types that are pointers to objects without qualifiers and null pointer constants. Certainly a `double` cannot be properly returned for a `void *` return type, since `double` is not a pointer at all.

Comment: In a 32-bit system the pointer is probably 4 bytes, so it cannot masquerade as a `double` which needs 8 bytes.

Comment: @WeatherVane Size matters not. Even if `double` and `void*` are the same size, there's still no implicit conversion. (Type *compatibility* is a much stronger requirement; the error message is slightly misleading.)

Comment: Please include the full error message, formatted as code, in the body of your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson indeed. But I believe there are some system calls that do hide data in a pointer, because it's their call mechanism. I was pointing out an impossibility, not a standards constraint.

Comment: "void * was supposed to return any datatype" --> No, that is incorrect.

Comment: Type `void *` can *point to* any data type.  But it cannot **be** any data type.

Answer (score 4):

The only things automatically convertible to `void *` are pointers to object types without qualifiers and null pointer constants, per C 2018 6.5.16.1 1.

`double` is not automatically convertible to `void *`.

You could return a pointer to `double` for a `void *` function, but you would need a `double` with lifetime extending beyond the function return, and there may be additional issues trying to implement a “generic” function this way. For one thing, when you return a `double *` or `int *` or other pointer type for a `void *`, the calling routine is not informed what type the pointer was before the conversion to `void *`. You need to write your program to handle that yourself, by providing some mechanism to inform the caller and have the caller convert the `void *` to the appropriate type.

Comment: Not only is `double` not *automatically* convertible to `void *`, but standard C does not provide for such a conversion to be performed *explicitly*, either (i.e. via typecast).  No behavior is defined for conversions between pointer types and floating-point types.

Answer (score 3):

There is no implicit conversion to `void*` from `double`. Such implicit conversions exist only for object pointer types and null pointer constants.

I wonder what you're expecting that code to do. If there were an implicit conversion, it would most likely take the bits of the `double` value `2.23` and interpret them as a pointer value of type `void*` (that's how explicit integer-to-pointer conversions typically work). The result would be garbage. In particular, it would not be a pointer to a memory location containing `2.23`.

(The language doesn't say much about the results of integer-to-pointer or pointer-to-integer conversions. There's no guarantee that they just reinterpret the bits; that's just the most common implementation. Avoid converting between integers and pointers until and unless you really need to *and* know what you're doing. And conversions between pointers and floating-point types are not permitted at all.)

The error message I get for your code is:

```
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:4:18: error: incompatible types when initializing type ‘double’ using type ‘void *’
    4 |     double res = _example_code();
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
c.c: In function ‘_example_code’:
c.c:8:12: error: incompatible types when returning type ‘double’ but ‘void *’ was expected
    8 |     return 2.23;
      |            ^~~~
```

The error message is actually a bit misleading. It's certainly true that `void*` and `double` are incompatible, but compatibility is not required here. For example, `int` and `long` are incompatible types, but you can legally return an `int` value from a function returning `long`, and the value will be implicitly converted. Type compatibility, as defined by the C standard, is a stronger condition that implicit convertibility. To a first approximation, a type is only *compatible* with itself (though there are other cases).

I've submitted a gcc bug report for the misleading error message:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107091

clang has a similar issue:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58066

(Of course the code is still in error.)

Comment: Re “take the bits … and interpret them … that's how explicit integer-to-pointer conversions typically work”: A conversion is a function that takes an input of one type and returns a result of (usually) another type that retains the input value to the extent possible. It is not a reinterpretation of bits. You may think of integer-to-pointer conversions as a reinterpretation of bits, but that is because there is a close correspondence between integers and addresses in a flat address space, so that the two notions have the same effect…

Comment: … But, for example, when a `double` is converted to an integer, the result is the integer whose value is the value of the integer part of the `double`, not a reinterpretation of the bits of the `double`. If somebody did have occasion to calculate an address using a `double`, we would most likely want to convert it by value, not by bits. E.g., array indices must be integer types, but there are situations where floating-point calculations are done for array lookups (e.g., interpolation), and it is the value of the `double` that matters, not its bits.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, that's why I wrote "most likely". In every implementation I've seen, conversions between integer and pointer types just reinterpret the bits (even on one implementation where pointer representation is such that the result of such a conversion could be dangerously misleading). Conversions between integers and pointers of differing sizes most likely zero-extend, or sign-extend, or truncate. ...

Comment: ... But all the standard says is that "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment", and that's in a non-normative footnote. I didn't think the language-lawyer details were relevant, but I'll add a few words clarifying the point.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have built-in generic containers, `void *` is a generic **data pointer**: you can store the value of a pointer to any data type into it and get back the original pointer by converting it back to the original type.

The effect of storing a `double` into a `void *` is not defined by the C Standard and your compiler complains that it is an invalid conversion.

For a specified list of types of objects, say `int`, `double` and `const char *`, you can define a generic container this way:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct generic {
    enum { INT, DOUBLE, STRING } type;
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
        const char *s;
    } u;
} generic;

generic function1(void);
generic function2(void);
generic function3(void);
int print_generic(const char *s, generic v);

int main() {
    generic v1 = function1();
    generic v2 = function2();
    generic v3 = function3();
    print_generic("v1: ", v1);
    print_generic("v2: ", v2);
    print_generic("v3: ", v3);
    return 0;
}

generic function1(void) {
    return (generic){ DOUBLE, { .d = 2.23 }};
}

generic function2(void) {
    return (generic){ INT, { .i = 42 }};
}

generic function3(void) {
    return (generic){ STRING, { .s = "Hello" }};
}

int print_generic(const char *s, generic v) {
    switch (+v.type) {
    case INT:    return printf("%s%d\n", s, v.u.i);
    case DOUBLE: return printf("%s%g\n", s, v.u.d);
    case STRING: return printf("%s%s\n", s, v.u.s);
    default:     return printf("%s%s\n", s, "unknown");
    }
}
```

Also note that `_example_code` is a reserved identifier. Do not start you identifiers with an underscore, these are reserved for the compiler's internal needs.